# Split a string (list of author names) into named components I can manipulate

Tags: javascript

I have a string containing a list of names (authors of a book)

`"John Doe, Jim Smith, Jane Elizabeth Doe"`

I want to output a string:

`'"Doe, John", "Smith, Jim", "Doe, Jane Elizabeth"'`

I managed to work it out for a single author.

```
let fullName = "John Doe";
let pieces = fullName.split(" ");
var lastName, firstName; 
  if (pieces.length >= 2) {
    firstName = pieces[0];
    lastName = pieces[pieces.length - 1];
  } else {
    firstName = pieces[0];
    lastName = "";
  }
let lastFirst = '"' + lastName + ", " + firstName + '"';
```

I think I need to do something like this...

```
let fullName = "John Doe, Jim Smith, Jane Elizabeth Doe";
  if (fullName.includes(",")) {
    let author = fullName.split(", ");
    var arrayLength = author.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
        let pieces = author[i].split(" ");
    }
  }
```

but now I'm stuck, any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the below approach with some comments

```js
const input = "John Doe, Jim Smith, Jane Elizabeth Doe"

const names = input.split(",")

const result = []

for (const name of names) {
  const nameParts = name.trim().split(" ") //remove reluctant space and break the string down into array items (names)
  const lastName = nameParts.pop() //take the last item
  nameParts.unshift(lastName + ",") //add the last item to the first position
  result.push(`"${nameParts.join(" ")}"`) //add "" to a name
}

const output = result.join(",") //make the entire array to become a string with a separator `,`


console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 2):

You were on the right track and almost got it. After getting the `pieces` array you just need to form a new string by changing the order of words in `pieces`.

```js
let fullName = "John Doe, Jim Smith, Jane Elizabeth Doe";
  if (fullName.includes(",")) {
    let author = fullName.split(", ");
    var arrayLength = author.length;
    var res = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
        let pieces = author[i].split(" ");
        let newName = "\"" + pieces[1] + ", " + pieces[0] + "\"";
        res.push(newName);
    }
  }
```

This is assuming all names consist of only 2 words. If there are more words within a name (for example, if you have a middle name as well), you can loop over the pieces array in reverse and append the individual words into `newName` assuming that you would still want to display the names in reverse order.

Comment: Thanks heaps @theleftwinger, that put me on the right track. Now to make it work in all cases (single author, author with middle names, hyphenated last names, etc.)